# SQL: Grouped table; delete reciprocal pairs?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a table like this called **inventory**, for example:

```
+----+------------+-------+
| id |Product_ID  | Count |
+----+------------+-------+
| 1  | 1          |     4 |
| 2  | 2          |     5 |
| 3  | 4          |     3 |
| 4  | 5          |     3 |
| 5  | 5          |    -3 |
| 6  | 2          |    -5 |
+----+------------+-------+
```

And the result of my query **GroupedInventory AS (SELECT id, Product_ID, Count FROM inventory ORDER BY Product_ID** gives me (stored in GroupedInventory):

```
+----+------------+-------+
| id |Product_ID  | Count |
+----+------------+-------+
| 1  | 1          |     4 |
| 2  | 2          |     5 |
| 6  | 2          |    -5 |
| 3  | 4          |     3 |
| 4  | 5          |     3 |
| 5  | 5          |    -3 |
+----+------------+-------+
```

And I want to delete the matching positive and negative results.  So in the end the table should turn into:

```
+----+------------+-------+
| id |Product_ID  | Count |
+----+------------+-------+
| 1  | 1          |     4 |
| 3  | 4          |     3 |
+----+------------+-------+
```

I deal with sequential languages and I just can't wrap my head around this.  My mind is telling me to loop through the table, store the pairs and then delete the pairs by id in the original table.

Comment: I don't think your specification is clear -- is it always two items that total to 0 or any number of items that total to 0?

Comment: What do you want if you have duplicates, but the sum is not zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with GroupedInventory as
(
 SELECT  Product_id, abs(sum(case when count < 0 then count else 0 end)) Negative, abs(sum(case when count > 0 then count else 0 end)) Positive 
 FROM inventory
 group by Product_id
)
delete from inventory
where Product_id in (select Product_id from GroupedInventory where positive = negative );
```

Although the validity also depends on unspecified rules, such as how many entries can exist for a given product_id.

Comment: This definitely works!  Thanks.  One question though, what if they weren't positive and negative? Say I added an extra column that was a foreign key which had "1" for add, "2" for remove?  How would I delete 1:2 pairs?

Comment: @Kevin Approximately the same; you would just change the case statements to look for the specific values instead of > 0 and < 0. The case statements are materializing them into distinct columns you can name anything you want. 



with GroupedInventory as
(
 SELECT  Product_id, abs(sum(case when count = 1 then count else 0 end)) Ones, abs(sum(case when count = 2 then count else 0 end)) Twos 
 FROM inventory
 group by Product_id
)
delete from inventory
where Product_id in (select Product_id from GroupedInventory where Ones = Twos );

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, Product_ID, SUM(Count)
FROM [GroupedInventory]
WHERE SUM(Count) <> 0
GROUP BY Product_ID, id
```

I'm not 100% positive that will work without testing it myself, let me know if you get a weird result.

Comment: What if there are three Product_IDs that sum to 0? I.E. -1, -2 and 3. Perhaps that's not the issue for OP.

Comment: Use HAVING instead of WHERE when using GROUP BY.

Answer (score 0):

Use this uqery:

```
SELECT 
  MIN(GI.ID) AS ID, GI.Product_ID, SUM(GI.Count) As COUNT
FROM 
  GroupedInventory AS GI
GROUP BY 
  GI.Product_ID
HAVING 
  SUM(GI.Count) <> 0;
```

I use `MIN` and `SUM` so as result you will have calculation of sum grouped to `MIN` ID. I don't know if this is desired result. It is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `OVER` clause with `PARTITION BY` AS well, You can [read it here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189461.aspx).
Here is the query with your given test data,

```
create table #temp
(id bigint,
 proid bigint,
 cnt bigint)


 insert into #temp
 values(1,1,4),
 (2,2,5),
 (3,4,3),
 (4,5,3),
 (5,5,-3),
 (6,2,-5)

 ;WITH cte 
 AS(
    SELECT id, proid, SUM(cnt) OVER(PARTITION BY proid) AS total 
    FROM #temp 
 )

 SELECT * 
 FROM cte 
 WHERE total <> 0


 Drop table #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
DELETE inventory
FROM inventory
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT Product_ID FROM inventory group by Product_ID HAVING SUM(Count)=0
    ) as t ON inventory.Product_ID = t.Product_ID
```